# String to Integer with CInt

Tags: excel, vba

I am copying a cell to a variable, converting it to an integer in a second variable, adding 1, and passing it back to the cell with the following code:

```vb
Option Explicit


Dim copyData As String
Dim copyNum As Integer

'read data
copyData = Cells(1, 4)

'convert to int
copyNum = CInt(copyData)

'advance by 1
copyNum = copyNum + 1

'print back to the sheet
Cells(1, 4) = copyNum
```

When this runs i get a type mismatch error when the line `copyNum = CInt(copyData)` runs. Why is it throwing an error? i don't understand why it thinks there's a mismatch.

PS, this error still happens if I declare copyNum as a double or a long.

Comment: Can only replicate the error if the cell is blank/empty, or has non-numeric values in the cell. Apart from that, it works for me. Can you give an example of Cell(1,4) contents, particularly a value that throws the mismatch error?

Comment: On a side note, why is copynum declared as double but its casted to long? You should cdbl as well

Comment: @Sgdva i had copynum declared as a long at one point, changed at some point debugging. not sure what cdbl is.

Comment: @njc in this case it's "1" in general format.

Comment: OK, I've replicated it with a double quoted string (number). You can try, copyNum = CLng(Replace(copyData, Chr(34), vbNullString)), to cater for double quoted strings. Chr(34) is the double quotation text.

Comment: @njc that doesn't work.

Comment: You are casting a number [long](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/data-types/double-data-type) to a variable declared as [double](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/data-types/double-data-type). Clng casts the value to long (is not the same as integer in declarations), Cdbl casts the value to double. You may run into problems later on if they are different in value. If there is a decimal on the cell you casted it to long will take away the decimal, but on the main code you expect that it could have decimals

Comment: @Sgdva edited my code, changed the declaration to int and CLng to CInt. still have the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in comments probably you have empty cell causing the error.
`Val()` function converts String to Double. Empty cell or non-numeric value will return 0. You can add some checks for that cases.
You can try this code:

```
Cells(1, 4) = Val(Cells(1, 4).Value) + 1
```

Or change `copyNum = CLng(copyData)` to `copyNum = Val(copyData)` if you need `copyNum` variable.